# How to move current line behind the line above it in Vim?

Tags: vim

How would I move the current line behind the line above it? Say I have:

```
    function foo()
      {
      ^ Cursor is here
```

And want to turn that into:

```
function foo() {
```

I am still new to vim, so what I do now is `i[backspace][backspace]...etc.` :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several ways:

- In normal mode, `kJ` or `kgJ` or `VkJ` or `VkgJ` (the last two commands do the same in visual mode).
  `k` will go to previous line, and `J` or `gJ` will merge with next line (`J` inserts a space inbetween, `gJ` just removes the EOL characters)
- In command mode, `:-,j` or `:-,j!`
  `-,` is a range that is abbreviation for `.-1,.` which means “from previous line to current line”
  `j` is the ex command for concatenating lines in a range. The banged (with exclamation mark) version acts like gJ.
- With a substitution: `:-s/\s*\n\s*//`
  `-` means previous line
  `:s` is probably known to you, else you should run `vimtutor`.
  `/\s*\n\s*/` is pattern for as many spaces as possible plus line terminator (matches different byte sequences according to the file format: LF, CR or CRLF) plus as many spaces as possible.
  Here, replacement pattern is empty.
- in insert mode, hit `CTRL-W` twice (each time it deletes a word, or leading whitespace on a line, or newline) (as [ib.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254635/ib) suggests, this depends on the `backspace` setting).

References:

- `:help J`
- `:help gJ`
- `:help k`
- `:help range`
- `:help :j`
- `:help pattern`
- `:help i_CTRL-W`

Comment: +1; Also, if you need to merge multiple lines with `gJ`, you can do `gJ` once, and hit the `.` key to repeat this action.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: or you can do *n* `gJ`, where *n* is the number of lines to join. note that `gJ` is equivalent to `2gJ` and that this is counter-intuitive (when using `relativenumber` you must do arithmetics).

Comment: anything to say if i am in insert mode?

Comment: One can use just `:-j` instead of `:-,j` for all lines except for the first one (in that case `:-,j` would do nothing while `:-j` would append the second line to the first one).

Comment: Joining lines with `Ctrl`+`W` in insert mode relies on whether the `backspace` option contains the `eol` flag.  It is probably more reliable to use `Ctrl`+`O`,`k`, `Ctrl`+`O`,`J`.

Comment: @ib.: thanks for your comments. About the last comment, it also depends whether `insertmode` is set. In this case: `CTRL-L kJ Esc`!

Comment: @Benoit:  Behavior of `Ctrl`+`O` in Insert mode does not depend on the `insertmode` option (in distinction from `Ctrl`+`L`).